# Conversion of factor to numeric returns zero

Tags: r, numeric, scientific-notation

Using R, I'm trying to convert a factor to numeric using `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.
Many of the x values are very small and I noticed that they turn into zero. For example
`as.numeric(as.character("5.79e-866"))` gives 0.
How can I avoid this and get the actual numeric value of 5.79e-866?

Comment: On the usual base `R` double vector (from official documention): *All R platforms are required to work with values conforming to the IEC 60559 (also known as IEEE 754) standard. This basically works with a precision of 53 bits, and represents to that precision a range of absolute values from about 2e-308 to 2e+308*. It is possible there is a package out there dealing with the precision you are asking for - but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you @sindri_baldur. I wasn't aware of the precision limitation in R. I found the Rmpfr package which offers the mpfr() function that does exactly what I need.